# Vercel/Next.js enable preview mode on production branch

Tags: next.js, vercel

When deploying a Next.js application via Vercel it would appear that on the [default production branch](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git#production-branch) enabling preview mode via [API](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git#production-branch) does not seem to work. I guess this makes sense from a semantical point of view, but is whats going on documented anywhere? I can't seem to figure out whats happening on a technical level.

Can somebody explain what exactly is happening here?